# Install Ubuntu 14 LTS next to windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi

I would like to install Ubuntu 14 LTS next to windows 10 (HP notebook). 
My disk partitions are these (GPT): http://postimg.org/image/apog4l7wh/ . I have disabled secure boot, fast boot and I have enabled legacy mode in bios. After reducing sda3 to make space, what partitions should I create? In which partition should I install bootloader (sda or sdaX)? Is it necessary to use legacy mode or can I use uefi mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it:

1. Put boot mode to UEFI
2. Put on Secure boot
3. Partitions:

   - ext4 (mount point /)
   - swap
   - efi
4. Install bootloader on efi

So, at the end, there are 2 efi partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same installation some time ago and the installation worked just fine, without disabling secure boot or anything (using UEFI).

I just made a new empty partition and started the ubuntu installation from the USB stick. After the installation everything worked and when rebooting,  grub2 showed up to let me choose which operating system to boot.

BTW: maybe consider to use the newer 16.04 which is also LTS.

Answer (score 0):

> I have disabled secure boot

This should be unnecessary, and as a general rule, is inadvisable. If you can't boot the installation medium with Secure Boot enabled, disabling it *might* fix the problem -- or you could have another issue

> fast boot

There are at least two features with similar names:

- The Windows Fast Startup feature *must* be disable to safely dual-boot with Ubuntu (or anything else). See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) for details. Note that it's also often necessary to [disable Hibernation,](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) too.
- Many EFIs have a feature with a similar name, which typically causes the firmware to take certain shortcuts in the startup process. These shortcuts sometimes make it difficult or impossible to select the boot device, so you may not be able to boot the Ubuntu installer; but if you can boot the Ubuntu installer, the firmware feature should have no other negative consequences.

> I have enabled legacy mode in bios

***DON'T DO THIS!!!!*** The result is likely to be one of two things:

- No effect. If you're lucky, enabling this feature will do nothing, except possibly increase your boot time by a couple of seconds.
- Create a mixed-mode installation. If you're unlucky, enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support will result in a BIOS-mode install of Ubuntu alongside an EFI-mode install of Windows. Such a setup is more difficult to boot -- sometimes to the point of impossibility. You should avoid this type of setup like the plague!

On *rare* occasions, enabling the CSM may be necessary -- but if it were needed on your computer, it would probably already be needed for Windows. Thus, you should undo this change before you attempt to install Ubuntu. For more on this subject, see [my Web page about it.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

As to your major question, there are lots of posts on this site about it, such as:

- [What are the partitions to create if I want to dual boot ubuntu 12.10 with Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235862/what-are-the-partitions-to-create-if-i-want-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-with-windo)
- [How to create partitions in Ubuntu while installing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179362/how-to-create-partitions-in-ubuntu-while-installing)
- [Partitions required for Installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280270/partitions-required-for-installing-ubuntu)